# Regex for json with negative lookahead

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I have the following json array:

```
    [
    {
      "roleId": 128,
      "roleName": "B",
      "Permissions": []
    },
    {
      "roleId": 310,
      "roleName": "ROLE",
      "Permissions": [
        {
          "permissionId": 8074,
          "isPermissionActive": true
        },
        {
          "permissionId": 2271,
          "isPermissionActive": true
        },
        {
          "permissionId": 8075,
          "isPermissionActive": true
        },
        {
          "permissionId": 2275,
          "isPermissionActive": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "roleId": 201,
      "roleName": "B",
      "Permissions": []
    },
    {
      "roleId": 5,
      "roleName": "B",
      "Permissions": []
    }
    ]
```

I need to select the `roleId` of the jsons with non null permissions. I've tried using a negative lookahead, but doesnt seem to work.
Before selecting the `roleId`, I wanted to get a correct match on the json so I've tried `\{(\s*.*?(?!"Permissions":\s*\[\]))*\}`, but it seems to match all the jsons and even the inner jsons of the permission array. How should change the look ahead to match properly. I'm currently matching in sublime text 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following Regex:

```
(?<="roleId": )\d*(?=(?:[^{]*"Permissions": \[(?!])))
```

Explanation: 
The first part `(?<="roleId": )\d*` uses positive lookbehind to find the rollId
The second part `(?=(?:[^{]*"Permissions": \[(?!])))` negative lookahead to find non-null permissions, and positive lookahead to find the rollId with the non-null permissions.
[See detailed explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/KksTTB/1)

Answer (score 1):

While this doesn't directly answer your question, I would like to point out  that it might be more natural to process JSON with JavaScript or with one of many languages that can easily convert JSON to native types.  Alternatively, you could use a JSON processing language such as `jq`:

```
jq '
  map( select(.Permissions != []) | .roleId ) 
'
```

which produces an array of role IDs with non-empty permissions.

Answer (score 1):

A lookbehind to check if the number is a "roleId".
And a lookahead to check if the "Permissions" have a mustache.

```
(?<="roleId": )\d+(?=[^\}]*?"Permissions":\s*\[\s*\{)
```

Test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/uwOMOJ/1)